# PDF of mesh emitter?

Tags: graphics, raytracing

I'm trying to learn multiple importance sampling (MIS) where I need to calculate the weight of a sample based on the PDF of each sampling technique. I understand the PDF from the BRDF, and the PDF of hitting a particular spherical light based on the light's radius. But for a mesh emitter, how do I calcuate the PDF of hitting the emitter? Is it just the solid angle of the emitting triangle?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what type of light it is. For example a mesh that is an area light has a `pdf = 1.f / Area();` where `Area()` is the surface area of that shape.
This is a naive implementation and to improve this, you could get the surface area of the mesh that is only visible from the point of intersection. This would mean a solid angle measurement.

For more details with implementation, refer to PBRT Chapter 14.6, "Sampling Shapes" in the 2nd edition of the book.